# Can i Use regex in with collect in cypher in neo4j

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

```
MATCH (p:Patient)-[]-(d:Disease)
WHERE (d.prefLabel CONTAINS 'Diarrhea' OR d.prefLabel CONTAINS 'Hypothyroidism')
WITH p, COLLECT(d.prefLabel) AS conditions
WHERE "Hypothyroidism, unspecified" IN conditions AND "Diarrhea, unspecified" IN conditions
RETURN p. patientld
LIMIT 25
```

I have this query I want to use regex where there is "Hypothyroidism, unspecified" so that I do not have to give full text to match is there any way of doing it?

Comment: What exactly is the regular expression are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

In Cypher, you can use the [=~](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/5/clauses/where/#query-where-regex) operator to use regular expressions.

But your query does not seem to need to use regular expressions. Here is a simplified version of your query:

```
WITH ['Diarrhea', 'Hypothyroidism'] AS diseases
MATCH (p:Patient)--(d:Disease)
WHERE ANY(x IN diseases WHERE d.prefLabel CONTAINS (x + ", unspecified"))
RETURN DISTINCT p.patientld
LIMIT 25
```

There is no need to first filter by "xyz" and then by "xyz, unspecified". You can just filter by the longer string.